# Pages are indexed but disappear after few days

Tags: google-search, search-engine-indexing

My pages get indexed after 1 day, but some days later disappear from search results.
Any idea why this happens?
I've been trying to find any of the usual problems like hidden links or other issues, but can't find anything wrong.

[Here is an example](http://www.onlinegameslist.org/facebook/smooty-tales). It was on first page until yesterday, today is gone. 
This is happening with all my pages lately, so I think it must be something common to all, but can't figure out what.

Comment: That page is still in the search results (it is still indexed), it's just that it is not ranking as highly (as it was?). I'm not sure if this is relevant these days... I have read that Google would sometimes boost the ranking of new sites (new pages?) for a period of time to allow new content to get noticed. Could this be the case here?

Comment: That may be indeed an explanation, what does not explain is why completely unrelated and full of garbage pages show up in search results instead of my pages, that are related and have useful information for users :(

Comment: this also recently happend to my page. i have many web site . every new keyword will indexed and then disapear after 1 or 2 days! i dont know whats wrong. but thisis maybe becuase of thier new algorithm that doesnt work correctly and they surly had to change it. be cuase all of my content was fresh content and they realy show bad result istead usefull.
at the lost here is one of my web site that cuased by this issue.

Answer (score 3):

> It was on first page until yesterday [...]

First page of what?
All you did was link to the page itself, then not tell us what you're searching for and expect to see it at the top of. But regardless:

> but some days later disappear from search results

You're also not explaining what this means.
As far as I can tell, nothing's "disappeared." A targeted search, eg. for:

```
site:onlinegameslist.org "smooty tales"
```

turns up the page you gave as example, right at top. So it hasn't disappeared. Whether Google thinks it's good enough to return as a top result for whatever your search terms are, or anything at all, is a different and constantly-changing matter. But it *is* in the index.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info, it was on Google first page search results for "smooty tales review" or "smooty tales game" without "". I could understand it fell down some pages if more relevant results appeared, but I simple can't find it in the first pages. This is happening with all pages, that makes me think of some kind of penalty. But when you look for the exact matches with "", the pages are indexed. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Maybe it was personalized results and you didn't realize it? How far back has it dropped? Did you set results to 100 per page and look for it?

Comment: I'm using a clean, logged off browser to do the search. Also I can see in Google analytics the difference. This is really strange, because the content is original, I was one of the first ones to write about it. And it is happening to all of my recent posts, they get indexed, stay indexed for about 5 to 7 days, and then disappear. I must have something from wordpress or theme causing this issue, but can't figure out what. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

That has also happened to my web pages as well, but they don't actually disappear, just move to the second, third pages etc. in the search results. To find a particular web page of your site on Google just search this way "site:example.com: page" Example (your web address) & page (the web page/keyword associated with a particular web page you are looking for)

In order for your website to rank #1 on Google, you not only need good content, but SEO as well. Such as strong keywords, good meta description, also place keywords into the title of your web page as well. This has drastically helped the homepage of my website to rank #1 in a Google search result.

Answer (score 0):

Well, They may claim to have worked upon to remove spam from search results but the reality is not so. I suppose that they’ll bring change in their new algorithm soon as they might have received tons of reconsideration request for original websites (which are legitimate and didnot copy content) which have been completely deindexed due to the changed algorithm.

Comment: Does this attempt to answer the question? This should perhaps be a comment, if anything.